# Indy 400 Bad Request exception

Tags: indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2 and am getting a `400 Bad Request` exception using `TIdHTTP.Get()`. I can enter the HTTP call string into any browser and it works correctly, but not in `Indy`.

My request string is:

```
accept text/html,*/*
accept charset  UTF-8
basicauthentication true
contentType Text/xml
UserAgent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MyApp)Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MyApp)
```

Comment: May you please add the code of your request, and the actual error message you are getting, not just the 400

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to be something other than a simple repetition of the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to future readers who are scanning through a list of search results. Repeating the tags does nothing useful. While you're making that [edit] , you cal also include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, as we can't debug code we cannot see. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages (especially [ask]) to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Something had to have happened recently to cause this change in behavior. Did you make a change in your code? Did the HTTP server make a change in their HTTP requirements? There is no way for anyone here to diagnose this issue without more information. Did you try sniffing the HTTP traffic from a web browser and compare it to the HTTP traffic from `TIdHTTP` to see what is different between them? Did you try setting a different `UserAgent`? Is there any hint provided inside the HTTP response headers or body data to describe what the server considers to be wrong with the request?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses and suggestions.  I discovered what was causing the problem. It appears that my URL had some embedded spaces in it that was triggering the bad request messages.

What was throwing me off is that pasting that same URL into a browser was working correctly but that same URL with indy was failing.  After correcting the issue with the embedded spaces it is working as expected.